# eclipse ecore editor exception on linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, ecore

I am having problem with opening **ecore** files in **eclipse on linux**. The stack looks like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The feature 'fbiz' is not a valid feature
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.BasicEObjectImpl.eStructuralFeature(BasicEObjectImpl.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.BasicEObjectImpl.eObjectForURIFragmentSegment(BasicEObjectImpl.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.getEObject(ResourceImpl.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.getEObject(ResourceImpl.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.setValueFromId(XMLHandler.java:2850)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.setAttribValue(XMLHandler.java:2755)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.SAXXMIHandler.handleObjectAttribs(SAXXMIHandler.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObjectFromFactory(XMLHandler.java:2229)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObjectFromTypeName(XMLHandler.java:2132)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObject(XMLHandler.java:2067)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.createObject(XMIHandler.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.handleFeature(XMLHandler.java:1876)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.processElement(XMLHandler.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.processElement(XMIHandler.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:1008)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.startElement(XMIHandler.java:163)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:175)
...
```

If I restart eclipse it can load and show first ecore file, but when I try to load another ecore file it gives the same exception.

I tried this with Luna and Mars versions and the latest ecore and various jre's the problem is the same. Googled alot, but no answer there. Based on my experience it looks like memory problem in java, because it works sometime. Any hints on how to fix it?

Comment: It looks a lot like your ecore model owned an illegal attribute (the 'fbiz' attribute). I'm pretty sure, 'fbiz' is not a meta-attribute from Ecore.

Comment: yes, it should be "ofbiz", and it doesn't depend on ecore file, it always "eat" first symbol when it throw exception. But sometime it works, so obviously problem is in another place.

Comment: Oh, ok, that different, you don't try to open an ecore file, but a model that conforms to one of your metamodels (defined as an Ecore model). What EMF says is that in your xmi model, there is a feature found named 'fbiz' and it cannot found it in your metamodel. Try to open your model as a text file, identify the 'fbiz' relation and either delete it or change its name to 'ofbiz' (risky but could work if the metamodel has not evolved a lot). Anyway, it looks like a "desync" between your model and your metamodel.

Comment: Actually the text(xml, ecore) file has only "ofbiz" strings inside, so no "fbiz" ones. I.e. the file is right and the problem is somewhere outside. Sometimes, during fresh start of eclipse the file works fine.

Comment: Your metamodel is deployed as a static one I suppose. Perhaps you have multiple version of the same metamodel registered on the same URI during eclipse start and following the order, one metamodel takes the lead?

Comment: Metamodel is Ecore.ecore and it is shown as registered in Preferences->Epsilon->EMF Registry. If I remove it then I get different error message: "org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore' not found."

Comment: Ok, it's a a little bit more clear, sorry for all the questions, but EMF can be really hard to debug withtout the env in local :). In the registry, keep the URI/package binding (otherwise, you will always have this exception). Could you post the problematic files in xmi format?

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for your interest and questions. I should mentioned that the problem doesn't depend on file, even Ecore.ecore itself can raise the exception. Yes, Eclipse with EMF is hard to debug, my guess is that it are linux and java which make it failed.

Comment: My pleasure, I hope we will be able to find a solution. I use eclipse mars under linux (archlinux), fortunately for me, everything works smoothly. Perhaps, try another eclipse install with the same workspace (without adding any new plugin)? If you can, be sure to get the modeling version.

Comment: I tried luna and mars versions with the smae workspace and with  the same result. Also tried different versions of plugins, no luck. I am running ubuntu 64, btw. Yes, I always used modeling versions.

Comment: Wow. At this point, it's quite strange. What seems to happend (regarding the stack trace) is that your EMF editor tries to open your XMI model, which is an instance of the Ecore metamodel, and fails to create the model because of an unknown 'fbiz' attribute (as this attribute does not exist in the Ecore metamodel). I already had these errors and it always was a metamodel evolution which broke the model, but in your case, as the opening of Ecore.ecore raise the same error, i'm not sure what it could be. Perhaps the URI of another metamodel colliding with the Ecore URI?

Comment: Because it works on fresh start of eclipse it gives me a belief that the problem isn't in ecore file and metamodel URI. What do you think about general Java memory problem, for example, if there is outofmemory exception and some java code silently catch it?

Comment: You mean 'it fails' on fresh start right? :) I know that the Java memory config for eclipse is always a little bit tricky (perhaps only for me). Here is the end of my eclipse.ini config:
`-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -server` and the launcher part: `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m`
Sorry I that I am not able to give a precise answer about your issue.

Comment: No, it works on fresh start, but when I am trying to open another file or reopen first it fails.

Comment: My bad, I wasn't sure I got it. I'm out of tricks up my sleeve. Perhaps, try to install the QVT plugin, it comes with a very handy "MetaModel Explorer" which enables you to see all the metamodel registered from plugins and your workspace. Perhaps you'll see something here (very big metamodel or something) that could fill up your jvm memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint, I will try and come back with result.